# React private route not renderring the Login component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to the react js. I am trying to implement the private route concept. so,

```
Main.js

class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
            hasUserLogIn: false,
            dataFetched: false,
            isFetching: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const template =
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/QuizSetupMain" component={QuizSetupMain} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingScreen} />
            </Switch>
        return (
            <div>
              {template}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        hasUserLogIn: state.LoginReducer.hasUserLogIn,
        isFetching: state.LoginReducer.isFetching
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

**Privatecomponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
    return <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            props => {
                return isAuthenticated ?
                    (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    )
                    :
                    (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/login",
                                state: { from: props.location }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
            }
        }
    />
};

const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
        // isAuthenticated  value is get from here
        isAuthenticated: state.LoginReducer.hasUserLogIn
    }
);


export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false }
)(PrivateRoute));
```

so, here what I wanted to do is if user has not logged in then user should be redirected to the login component.otherwise user should redirect to the landingscreen components. so, I did in the following way.

but it is adding the `/login` in the url but that component is not getting renderd. so, can any one help me with this ?

```
export function sendUserJd(data, dispatch) {
    dispatch(setFlag());
    history.push('/');
    return {
        type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
        data: data,
    }
}
```

I am doing this in the action  to redirect the user.

Comment: shouldn't your login page be a normal (non-private) route?

Comment: sorry, but I am really new to this. can you suggest me ?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that you need to correct,

First:The login route need not be a PrivateRoute since an unauthenticated user should be able to access it'

Second: You need to wrap your Routes with a `Router` which is the Provider at some level in the parent components

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
            hasUserLogIn: false,
            dataFetched: false,
            isFetching: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        const template =
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/QuizSetupMain" component={QuizSetupMain} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={LandingScreen} />
            </Switch>
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                  {template}
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: actually,   You need to wrap your Routes with a Router which is the Provider at some level in the parent components   I did not understand this line. a bit explanation will definetely help. and this is working for me , Thanks a lot @shubham . You are excellent.

Comment: and Is that right where I have added  '/' which will be my home screen on successfully login ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate what I meant is that you need to add a Router component as a wrapper of Route once in the hierarchy. The Router can be <BrowserRouter> or <HashRouter> or <Router> with custom history prop.

Comment: Yeah, Got this one :-)   sorry a bit late.

Comment: after successfully login, now It is still showing the login page .

Comment: It takes some time to change that route in the url and then still it gives the login page

Comment: That might be because the authentication props is not getting available to PrivateRoute at the time you want to visit it

Comment: okay I have implemented the privateRoute component. Is there any thing that needs to be changed in this ?

Comment: yes, the state is not getting updated may be because of that

Comment: How are you updating the reducer state

Comment: I am changing it in the reducer file .

Comment: Actually, shubham after the login , then privateRoute is not getting called itself.

Comment: Are you redirecting to user to some route after logging in

Comment: yes I am , to the  /jobs route . using histroy.push

Comment: @ganeshkaspate , I don't see this particular route, defined with PrivateRoute in your sample

Comment: Sorry, actually what I am trying to do is , / will be the landingscreen. Now, if user has not logged in then he should be redirected to the loginpage or else to the / that means landingscreen. Now, if user somehow changes the route then also it should redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

The login route needs to be public (not private) coz that is the page through which your users can authenticate themselves

Essentially, replace

`<PrivateRoute exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />`

with

`<Route exact path='/login' component={LoginComponent} />`

Comment: Hi, is there anything that I need to change in my privateRoute.js. and also is my routing order right